# Installing tex in Ubuntu

Tags: software-installation

I am following [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu) to install vanilla texLive and don't know what to do with the following instructions:

> Create the following PATHs in your manpath, infopath and PATH for
>   finding your new installation in TeXLive 2017
>
> export PATH=/usr/local/texlive/2017/bin/x86_64-linux:$PATH
>   export INFOPATH=$INFOPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/info 
>   export MANPATH=$MANPATH:/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/doc/man

Would you help me? I don't know where to put those lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those go in your `.bashrc`. It's located in your home directory (example `/home/hernan/.bashrc`).

Anything added to `.bashrc` will load each time a new bash shell is loaded, so you will just need to run `bash` again, or just open a new terminal window.